# How to exchange SAML assertion for an OAuth token

Tags: java, spring, authentication, oauth-2.0, saml

I am working on a client's Spring (SAML Authenticated) application backend. I need to embed a restricted Grafana dashboard on the front-end. It's been suggested that I can exchange the SAML Assertion for an OAuth token (JWT format).

I have created a SAML authentication and a OAuth authentication prototype that I can use to grasp this concept.

I can find little information about this exchange, and those that I do find are a little lost on me; I am not a spring expert.
Can someone please explain how I would go about doing this, or link me to a tutorial that may be of some assistance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMHO you don't need anything special if Grafana has configured OAuth auth and you are using only one IDP.